# Installing JavaHL 1.6 on CentOS

Tags: svn, centos, subclipse, javahl

I'm looking to install the 1.6 version of JavaHL on CentOS, which proves to be more tricky then expected.

Has someone succeed doing so and can point a repo for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved that issue on rhel5u5 64 bit, but doing a ckeckout from the latest stable tag and doing a full build of subversion and the javahl binding
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.6.11 svn-1-6-11

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/subversion --enable-javahl --with-jdk=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun.x86_64
make 
make install
make javahl
make install-javahl
```

You will need to get many dependencies from the repositories though.

Comment: I didn't mention this before, but if it is a production box you should try building it in another box(dev or a temp one) and then moving the binaries to the prod one.

Comment: My saviour ! Several hours lost on this $^$ù$ javahl before finding your answer. Thanks a lot. (on RedHat 5 with SVN 1.7, works the same.)

Answer (score 8):

On my CentOS 5 machine, the following worked like a charm:

`yum install subversion-javahl`

It pulled the rpm from the dries repo.  If you don't have yum configured to pull from dries: http://dries.ulyssis.org/rpm/clientconfig.html

Remember, as has been said by others here, that JavaHL is pretty version-sensitive - I'm running subclipse 1.6 / subversion 1.6, so I installed JavaHL 1.6.  [Make sure you're installing the right version](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL).

Answer (score 1):

CollabNet provides an RHEL/CentOS RPM that includes JavaHL.

http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/redhat.html

Comment: Thanks for advice, but it throws me the following error:

Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.so.0.0.0: /opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.so.0.0.0: undefined symbol: _ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = /opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib

Ever managed to get it working?

Comment: The problem actually seems to be here:

undefined symbol: _ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE

Comment: CollabNet's svn client RPM doesn't work with the most recent version of Eclipse either.

Comment: The CollabNet RPM works fine with Subclipse, but you do need to get the right version.  Subclipse 1.8.x requires SVN 1.7.x and Subclipse 1.6.x requires SVN 1.6.x.

Answer (score 0):

To do this for JavaHL 1.7 on centos5.8:

```
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.7.5/ svn-1-7-5
cd svn-1-7-5/
./get-deps.sh  #<---- not sure if that one's necessary.
. autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/opt/subversion --enable-javahl --with-jdk=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0
make
make install
make javahl
make install-javahl
```

Answer (score 0):

on Centos 6.3:

```
yum install subversion-javahl.x86_64
```